# How to sort a table knowing row position?

Tags: javascript

I have a table:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

An array that tells where every row should come `[{index: 2},{index: 1},{index: 0}]` (first row is the last from the array, second row is the `1` in array and third row `0` from the array).

Comment: Sort array using which you output your table.

Comment: That's an awful approach. With 10,000 rows sorting table DOM directly would top approximately 100,000 iterations.

Comment: jQuery plugin - sortable table might help. http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: @SandeepGB I am looking for help with a specific programming problem, not por a plugin to solve (questionably) my problems.

Comment: @Guy Maybe I misunderstood your question. So let me clarify things. You have a table and array using which you reorder you table?

Comment: I have an array that dictates the new order in the table. Correct.

Comment: @Guy What I've recommended in my first comment was that instead of reordering, generate that table according to your array.

Comment: @PLB, That's sort of similar what am I doing already. See my answer below. Though, the bottleneck was NodeList cloning. Instead I am using now `Array.prototype.slice`. Will post an update soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach.

```
// create a new temporary tbody outside the DOM (similar to jQuery's detach)
var tbody_tmp   = document.createElement('tbody');

// itterate through the array in the order of a new table
for(var i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i++)
{
    // make a copy of current row (otherwise, append child removes the row from the rows array and messes up the index-finder; there got be a better way for this)
    var row     = rows[data[i].index].cloneNode(true);

    tbody_tmp.appendChild(row);

    // reset the index to reflect the new table order (optional, outside the sample)
    data[i].index   = i;
}

// Note that tbody is a jquery object
tbody.parent()[0].replaceChild(tbody_tmp, tbody[0]);
```

Though, the cloning approach is slow. With 10,000+ records it takes ~1200ms. Furthermore, a jQuery-less approach is preferable.

Posting this in case someone else might find it simple enough for their needs (with less than 1,000 rows).

---

After hours of restless thinking, I've ended up with the following. If this sample isn't enough, I've written a whole blog post explaining the logic behind it, http://anuary.com/57/sorting-large-tables-with-javascript.

```
// Will use this to re-attach the tbody object.
var table       = tbody.parent();

// Detach the tbody to prevent unnecessary overhead related
// to the browser environment.
var tbody       = tbody.detach();

// Convert NodeList into an array.
rows            = Array.prototype.slice.call(rows, 0);

var last_row    = rows[data[data.length-1].index];

// Knowing the last element in the table, move all the elements behind it
// in the order they appear in the data map
for(var i = 0, j = data.length-1; i < j; i++)
{
    tbody[0].insertBefore(rows[data[i].index], last_row);

    // Restore the index.
    data[i].index   = i;
}

// Restore the index.
data[data.length-1].index   = data.length-1;

table.append(tbody);
```